# Typescript mixin: the return type of mixed method

Tags: typescript, mixins

I followed the example of Typescript Mixins over there: [mixin](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-22), and did some changes,

The following codes shows the relationship: Point <= TaggedPoint <= MadedTaggedPoint, and there is a 'export' method return an object that composite by properties from base class and current class,The problem is when mixin is applied multiple times, then instance of the generated class can not recognize the return type of the mixed 'export' method correctly:

```
    class Point {
  constructor(public x: number, public y: number) { }
  export() {
    return { x: this.x, y: this.y };
  }
}
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
function Tagged<T extends Constructor<Point>>(Base: T) {
  return class extends Base {
    _tag: string;
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      this._tag = "";
    }
    export() {
      return {
        ...super.export(),
        _tag: this._tag,
      };
    }
  };
}
function Madded<T extends Constructor<Point>>(Base: T) {
  return class extends Base {
    _mad: string;
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      this._mad = "";
    }
    export() {
      return {
        ...super.export(),
        _mad: this._mad,
      };
    }
  };
}

const TaggedPoint = Tagged(Point);

let tag = new TaggedPoint(10, 20);
tag._tag = "hello";
// typescript does not complaint about ._tag
console.log(tag.export()._tag);


const MadedTaggedPoint = Madded(TaggedPoint);
const mad = new MadedTaggedPoint(10, 20);
// typescript complaints:
// [ts] Property '_tag' does not exist on type '{ _mad: string; x: number; y: number; }'.
// because MadedTaggedPoint mixed TaggedPoint, so I thought mad.export() shuold have _tag property
console.log(mad.export()._tag);
```

Comment: You have a couple of typos .. `console.log(point.export()._mad);` should be `console.log(mad.export()._mad);` and in `Madded`  you export `_tag` not `_mad`. But there is a real problem here as well. If you make the changes I suggest, the final `mad.export()` will return an object with `_mad` but not `_tag` is this your real issue ?

Comment: Sure,I corrected typos, because MadedTaggedPoint mixed TaggedPoint, so I thought mad.export() shuold have _tag property

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way mixins create the result type. If we look at the final type of the export metod we see that is has 3 overloads:

```
export(): { _mad: string; x: number; y: number;}
export(): { _tag: string; x: number; y: number;}
export(): { x: number; y: number;}
```

So the problem is that instead of overriding the method, you end up creating multiple overloads for it. I suspect that the instance type of the mixin ends up being `TNewMethods & InstanceType<T>`.

We can override the instance type if we do a bit of surgery on the types to replace the `export` method:

```
class Point {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) { }
    export() {
        return { x: this.x, y: this.y };
    }
}
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type OverrideExportReturn<T extends Constructor<Point>, TNewReturn> = {
    new (...args: (T extends new (...a: infer A) => any ? A: [])):
        { export(): ReturnType<InstanceType<T>['export']> & TNewReturn } & 
        Pick<InstanceType<T>, Exclude<keyof InstanceType<T>, 'export'>>
} & Pick<T, keyof T>

function Tagged<T extends Constructor<Point>>(Base: T){
    class Tagged extends Base {
        _tag: string;
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
            this._tag = "";
        }
        export() {
            return {
                ...super.export(),
                _tag: this._tag,
            };
        }
    };
    return Tagged as unknown as OverrideExportReturn<typeof Tagged, {_tag: string }>;
}
function Maded<T extends Constructor<Point>>(Base: T) {
    class Maded extends Base {
        _mad: string;
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
            this._mad = "";
        }
        export() {
            return {
                ...super.export(),
                _mad: this._mad,
            };
        }
    };
    return Maded as unknown as OverrideExportReturn<typeof Maded, {_mad: string }>;
}

const TaggedPoint = Tagged(Point);

let point = new TaggedPoint(10, 20);
point._tag = "hello";
console.log(point.export()._tag);


const MadedTaggedPoint = Maded(TaggedPoint);
const mad = new MadedTaggedPoint(10, 20);
console.log(mad.export()._mad);
console.log(mad.export()._tag);
```